# Events for Ldap in Bro IDS

Tags: events, ldap, bro

I have to implement a dsniff version for bro as my final year project. So I started by writing bro scripts where I use protocol events that were implemented by Bro. The thing is Bro didn't implement events for all the protocols and LDAP is one of protocol that suffer from absence of events in BRO. So I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this. I mean : Do I need to add dissectors and events for theses protocols, or do I need to use some functionality of that I missed? (I'm newbie in Bro)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, dsniff is a collection of tools. What do you want Bro to do? Analyze LDAP traffic?

Comment: Let's say I want to analyze Ldap traffic, how I would do that?

Comment: You would have to write a new analyzer, because Bro doesn't ship with one. LDAP, and in particular ASN.1, is a *horrible* protocol when it comes to parsing. It's too specific of a task for an SO question, I encourage you to ask at the Bro mailing list.

Comment: Write a protocol analyzer for LDAP using BinPAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others that want to do the same as me, there's no analyser implemented for ldap. But this not a big problem because there's a handfull tool that helps us to write, simply and easily, analysers of protocols that uses Tcp or UDP as transport layed. This tools is called Binpac. Here's a link of a quickstart up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eDIl9y6ZnM.
And for people who wanted to know what we have managed to do for the project Bro-Dsniff, here's the link of git : https://github.com/rsabir/bro-dsniff